# Click event working on a single table row?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem with selecting a single row of a table in jQuery which is identified with a class `edit` and then a variable number when defined, so my first row would have a class `edit1`, the second one `edit2` and so on.

My concern is that I can fire the click event on the very last row in my table and I obviously get why, but I can't find information on how to actually dynamically select those rows.

I tried **.each** method like this:

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
        $('.edit{{server->id}}').on('click', function (){
                $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
                $(this).addClass('form-group');
                $('div.editable').addClass('form-control');
                $('div.hidbtn').removeAttr('hidden');
        });
 });
```

And it's obviously not working because my `{{server->id}}` here just refers to the last `{{server->id}}` taken from a foreach that creates the rows.

How can I put this in a way to select every single row and fire that click event for every single one ?

A foreach inside the script ?

I'm sorry if this can result such a stupid question..

I'm using Laravel 5.4 by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the every `.edit` you bind event to inside of each `tr`?

Comment: You are not _firing_ any events here, you are attaching event handlers. If you want to append the click handler to all elements, then just use a common class or different selector based on structure to select them. Having a “numbering” in class names is rather nonsense to begin with.

Comment: the client has no idea how many loops were made, but he can count the `tr`. You can either generate the `on('click')` code for each row in PHP, or echo the code to build an array or `id` for this purpose. However, as stated in another comment, if you never use your classes to select elements one by one, you can change to a generic class `edit`. If you do, maybe better to add a second generic class to be able to select all elements in one go to bind handlers

Comment: @debute yes, if I inspect the tr class, every row has its 'edit1',  'edit2' and so on

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry for my mistake, I do not want to handle the event on every row at once, just the one I click on, that's why I thought of numbering every row.

Comment: _Binding_ the event handler to multiple elements at once, does not mean _handling_ the event for all elements at once.

Answer (score 0):

When you go through the table by each tr and needs to bind an event to the element `.edit` inside of every row, then you can just "find" that element and bind the event to it.

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.edit').on('click', function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried like this but it's not even changing the values I needed to change :/

Comment: You can fire element like `$(this).find('.edit').trigger('click');` but better way is `$('table tr .edit').trigger('click');` without `each`. And you said _My concern is that I can fire the click event on the very last row_ so maybe this one `$('table tr .edit').last().trigger('click');` - also without `each`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var id=1;
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $('.edit'+id).on('click', function (){
        $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
        $(this).addClass('form-group');
        $('div.editable').addClass('form-control');
        $('div.hidbtn').removeAttr('hidden');
    }); 
    id+=1;
});
```

Or else do like this
HTML:-

```
<td onclick="clickFunctio()"></td>
```

Jquery:-

```
   function clickFunctio() {
       $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
       $(this).addClass('form-group');
       $('div.editable').addClass('form-control');
       $('div.hidbtn').removeAttr('hidden');
   }
```

Comment: i think you should remove the incrementation from the bound function, it should be in the `each`

Comment: If there will be IDs like `1, 2, 4, 5`, then fifth element won't be binded, since ID 3 is missing, then `each` will run just 4 times.